# Connecting to MySQL Database with ODBC

Tags: mysql, odbc, database-connection, unicenta

I am running a MySQL Database on my local PC which stores data for my Point of Sale system. I am able to work with that database no problem using the POS software as well as my website software. However, when trying to make a connection using `ODBC` to allow my bar-code generating software to connect, I get the below error.

I have tried "localhost", "127.0.0.1", and "127.0.0.1:3306" - all give me the same error... Any tips?

[image: Connection failed]

Comment: Based on the error message, you are using a SQL Server ODBC Driver to connect to a MySQL database, which will not work. You need to use a MySQL ODBC Driver (there are open source and 3rd party options available).

Comment: Got it working! Turns out the ODBC installer doesn't actually install the ODBC... it just installs an installer. LOL
After running that newly installed installer - all is well and the database connection works. :)